# Can’t select database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wamp, wamp-server

Я пытаюсь использовать Wordpress на локальном компьютере. В соответствии с руководством, которое я использую, я установил wampserver, в папке C: / wamp64 / www создал папку copycat и загрузил туда WordPress, создал базу данных с именем copycat с помощью PHPMyAdmin, запустил localhost / copycat в браузере Chrome и столкнулся с проблемой:

"Невозможно выбрать базу данных. Мы смогли подключиться к серверу базы данных (что означает, что у вас есть имя пользователя и пароль в порядке), но не смогли выбрать базу данных copycat. Вы уверены, что она существует? Имеет ли пользователь root право использовать copycat database? В некоторых системах имя вашей базы данных начинается с вашего имени пользователя, поэтому оно будет похоже на username_copycat. Может ли это быть проблемой? Если вы не знаете, как настроить базу данных, вам следует обратиться к вашему хосту. Если все в противном случае вы можете найти помощь на форумах поддержки WordPress. "

Я проверил все эти рекомендации: база данных существует, у пользователя есть все необходимые разрешения (отображаются в PHPMyAdmin), а имя базы данных не имеет префикса с именем пользователя. Я не знаком с php, MySQL и WordPress, поэтому чем проще ответ, тем лучше. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны дать полные права доступа вашему пользователю (copycat) к базе данных copycat.

Откройте phpMyAdmin, выберите в главном меню "Учётные записи пользователей", с строке вашего пользователя кликните "Редактировать привилегии", на открывшейся странице нажмите кнопку "База данных", введите имя базы данных в строке ввода "Добавить привилегии для следующих(ей) баз(ы) данных:" и нажмите кнопку "Вперёд".

После выполнения этой операции страница должна выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в том, что я этот момент уже проверил: User account 'root'@'localhost', privilages - all privelages, GRANT - Yes. Все чекбоксы отмечены, с галочкой.

Comment: Даны как global, так и database-specific: all privilages.

Comment: @ИльяКуц ты "проверил" рута, а не copycat.

Comment: Я, видимо, не указал в описании, но root - имя пользователя, которому предоставляются права, а copycat - имя базы данных и папки, где лежит wordpress. Мне кажется, что причина не в правах. Либо существую ещё какие-то мифические права, поскольку описанное выше я проверил и все чекбоксы отмечены.

Comment: У вас что написано в wp-config.php в строке `define('DB_USER', '...');`?

Comment: Насколько я понял, после всех манипуляций я и должен получить wp-config.php на основе вводимых мной данных. Т. е. я выбрал язык, потом заполняю форму, где указываю имя базы данных, имя пользователя, пароль и т.д. потом должен быть ещё какой-то шаг. А вконце, как результат wordpress сконфигурирован. Пока что есть только wp-config-sample.php в котором значения по умолчанию типа "database_name_here". Но я уже пробовал вручную поменять эти значения или создать wp-config.php в первом случае ничего не меняется, во втором получаю ошибку, что wp-config уже создан, что-то там пропуская последние шаги.